# codeigniter adding www to url in htaccess is stoping POST requests to work

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, .htaccess, post

I have encountered a rather strange issue while adding `www` to the urls in `.htaccess`. I have a codeigniter based site and adding `www` to all urls. But my `Post` request have stopped working.
Here is the content of my apache .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
#for adding www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|public) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I am using `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`

and it does work fine with non `www` urls but it stops `POST` requests working after adding `www` as stated in above. I have even tried `REQUEST_URI`, but it didn't help.
some other settings i have are.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
```

and in autoload `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

I guess the problem is that the 302 redirect after adding `www` does not understand `POST` data.

Comment: I assume all urls actually begins with `www` and not `wwww` as you write in your post?

Comment: Yes that was by mistake corrected it.

Comment: This question is not best placed on StackOverflow, consider posting it to ServerFault, because it is a non programming topic.

Answer (score 1):

Change your base URL from:

```
http://example.com
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the 301 redirect within .htaccess, just bake that logic into your app.

For example on every request you could do:

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www') === FALSE) {

    $domain_with_www = 'http://www.example.com';
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ("location: ".$domain_with_www.$this->uri->uri_string);
}
```

You can get this to run on every request by extending CI_Controller. See this for more info on that: http://codeigniter.tv/a-10/Extending-the-core-MY_Controller-and-beyond

Comment: is this really the right way to do it? it will unnecessary call the controller when it should not, I know people have been doing it through the .htaccess